# Android 5.1 make background running APP slow and timer imprecise

Tags: android, timer

My team has app which will handling real-time audio stream. What we doing is to get the audio from server and decoding it into PCM by MediaCodec in a thread then send to AudioTrack to play in another thread.
In Android 4.x, there's no problem when APP is running in background. However, in 5.x, it not work in background.

By logcat, we found two issues when App is running in background.
First, timer get slow. We use a timer to send PCM to AudioTrack periodically and we use Handler.sendMsgDelay() as suggested by Android for efficiency. But the test shows that when running in background, Handler get the msg much more later than in foreground(we wanna 20ms, but it turn to 50~60ms). We tried java.util.Timer but with same result in background. We try to set the thread to be max priority. But no effect either.

Second, even the MediaCodec running slow in background. We found that we can get decoded data from MediaCodec every 7~8 ms when running in foreground while 30~50ms in background!

We have download some APP like online radio from google play and run it in Android 5.1. There's no such problem when running in background. So, there must be someway to avoid it. Unfortunately, we don't how...

I know that there must be some power-saving policy in Android 5.1 to make background running app's thread get less CPU occupation. But google must open another window when he closed one. Is there new API to allow APP running in background just like in foreground? Or other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreground Service and your problem will be gone.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it at first and share the result here.